# How to merge two different object from JSON data

Tags: angularjs, arrays, json, concatenation

Hi I need some help with this code snippet. The output that I get is multiple different objects of JSON data. But I want to extract the destination data then merge them as an array. But all the data I get is only one data merge as an array, one by one.
Here is the output: [image]

```
$scope.findHospital = function(){

    $ionicLoading.show({
        template: '<ion-spinner icon="bubbles"></ion-spinner><br/>Acquiring location!'
    });

    var posOptions = {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: 20000,
        maximumAge: 0
    };

    $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(posOptions).then(function (position) {
        var lat  = position.coords.latitude;
        var long = position.coords.longitude;
        var infowindow;

        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);

        var mapOptions = {
            center: myLatlng,
            zoom: 16,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
        service.nearbySearch({
            location: myLatlng,
            radius: 5000,
            type: ['police']
        }, callback);

        function callback(results, status) {
            if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    createMarker(results[i]);
                }
            }
        }

        function createMarker(place) {
            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
            geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
                var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  map: map,
                  position: place.geometry.location
                });
                var request = { reference: place.reference };

                service.getDetails(request, function(details, status) {
                    console.log(details);

                    var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins="+results[0].formatted_address+"&destinations="+details.formatted_address+"&key=AIzaSyDDxMGpu5SP5XwZGrKw5BQWl_r2dgLgpPY";
                    var distances = [];

                    $http.get(url).then(function(response){
                        var str = response.data.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text;

                        distances = distances.concat(str);

                        console.log(distances);
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

CODE UPDATED!

Comment: Can you loop through the arrays with an angular.forEach and push each item onto the array?

Comment: erm how should I do that can you show me an example?

Comment: @MarkS. after I add the angular.foreach is still the same it only loops one data one by one not all together

Comment: distances is initializing everytime as I suspect, you have above code in some loop.

Comment: But i didnt declare any loop I juz call the url and the json data return the data one by one and initialize everytime

Comment: Assuming from latest code, I've posted an answer. please check it out !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly suspect, `distances` array is initializing everytime when `createMarker` method is called. So, put your `distances` in global scope. i.e. just above your resolving `getCurrentPosition` promise.

```
var distances = [];
$cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(posOptions).then(function (position) {
// your code
```

and remove distances intialization from inner code.

Comment: Nice it succeed already thanks so much lolcoder you are the bomb man

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need!! A array outside of your function `createMarker`. When you call `$http.get`, you should concatenate the response with your `distances` array.

```
var distances = []; // HERE

function createMarker(place) {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
        var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: place.geometry.location
        });
        var request = { reference: place.reference };

        service.getDetails(request, function(details, status) {

            var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins="+results[0].formatted_address+"&destinations="+details.formatted_address+"&key=AIzaSyDDxMGpu5SP5XwZGrKw5BQWl_r2dgLgpPY";

            $http.get(url).then(function(response){
                var str = response.data.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text;

                distances = distances.concat(str); // HERE
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: hi kevin is still the same is still return the same output

Comment: Can you show a little bit more of your code?? In your snippet I only see one call to the `$http.get`.

Comment: I'm sorry. I need more information of your code. But, basically, you need to declare the `distances` array outside of the function where is the actual code.

Comment: I juz declare outside it returns empty